# Suggested App iOS Geofence

Tags: ios, geolocation

I am aware that suggested apps on the lock screen can be triggered by iBeacons, but only if the app is already installed. However, sometimes the OS displays suggested apps based on geofences that may or may not already be installed. Can you register geofences for your app? Or is this something Apple does for you?

Comment: This is automatically done by Apple.

Comment: Aww, okay. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As rebello95 said, this is automatically done by Apple.

This part of the lock screen is also used for Handoff, so even if there's a suggested app geofence, it may not show that if you're using Handoff.